# How to read 2 dimensional JSON arrays in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

The following is a example of a JSON array:

`{"names":["mrx-prj","mry-prj"],"id":["4-prj","3-prj"]}`

How can I read the values in names and id seperately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a two dimensional array, it is an json object with two values `obj.names` and `obj.id` each of which are an array value.

The names array can be accessed using `obj.names` where `names` is the key of the array in the json object, same way id array can be accessed via `obj.id`.

```
var obj = {"names":["mrx-prj","mry-prj"],"id":["4-prj","3-prj"]}
var names = obj.names;
var ids = obj.id
for(var i = 0; i< names.length; i++){
    console.log(names[i]);
    //do what ever you want to do with names[i];
}
for(var i = 0; i< ids .length; i++){
    console.log(ids [i]);
    //do what ever you want to do with ids [i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

say your object is data .. you can do

```
 for(var i = 0; i< data.names.length; i++){  //loop to get names
   alert(data.names[i]);
 }

for(var i = 0; i< data.id.length; i++){ //loop to get ids
   alert(data.id[i]);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

if your jason is returning  from a PHP file the you can try this:

```
$.getJSON('your-json-string-file.php', function (data) {

  $.each(data, function(key, val) {
    alert(key +'=>'+ val)
  });

});
```

or you can try this:

```
$.getJSON('your-json-string-file.php', function (data) {

    $.each(data, function(key1, val1) {
        $.each(val1, function(key2, val2) {
            alert(key2 +'=>'+ val2)
        });
    });

});
```

Hope this will help you